# How to upgrade birtviewer 3.7.2 to 4.3.1 on tomcat server

Tags: tomcat, birt

Can anyone point me to the documentation on doing this? There are already pre existing reports on the birt viewer and files that i'm not supposed to touch. So i'm not quite sure what will be affected but i have been tasked to upgrade it. The birtviewer was deployed via a war file. Any help on this would be very much appreciated thank you.

Comment: Did you get a solution to this yet?

Answer (score 0):

I am writting this answer durring a conversion from 4.2.1 to 4.3.1 I do not yet have it up and running and have not completely worked out where all my issues are.

**First**: Do not attempt the upgrade on a production server/file without testing it in a non-production universe first.

**Second**: Apache uses "runtime" files from BIRT that were downloaded when your current version was created.  These are on the [download page](http://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/) farther down "Latest BIRT Runtime Release "

- Assuming the current path is C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\Birt
- Copy & Paste the files in "WebViewerExample" to "webapps/Birt"
- Restart Tomcat

Supporting directions at http://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/deploy/viewerSetup.php or http://wiki.eclipse.org/BirtPOJO_Viewer_Tomcat_Deployment